# Uniqueness of Irreversible and adiabatic processes in finite time

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, reversibility, adiabatic

Let the external intensive and extensive "mechanical" variables be denoted by $Y_k, X_k$. These variables are well defined irrespective of the system is in equilibrium or not. For an adiabatic process then we always have $dU=\sum_k Y_kdX_k$. Assume that the thermal and caloric equations of the system are given.

Now let us start from an arbitrary equilibrium state, that is both the external and the system's internal parameters are equal $Y_k^0, X_k^0$ with internal energy  and entropy denoted by $U^0, S^0$. Now let the external control parameters vary according to some prescribed time function, i.e., $Y_k(t), X_k(t)$ ending in the *equilibrium* state $Y_k^1, X_k^1$ and $U^1$, a pure work process, such that the initial entropy is not the same as the final one. Since we assumed that the process is adiabatic the system entropy must increase $S^1 > S^0$ and the process is *irreversible*.

My question has two parts:

1. given the start and end states, $\mathscr P^0= \{Y_k^0, X_k^0, U^0, S^0\}$ and $\mathscr P^1=\{Y_k^1, X_k^1, U^1, S^1\}$, are the control functions $Y_k(t), X_k(t)$ unique? In other words, can there be more than one irreversible adiabatic processes that start and end in the same equilibrium starting and ending states?
2. if the control functions are not unique then how "large" is that set of function and how to characterize them analytically?

Comment: Are you asking whether there can be more than 1 adiabatic irreversible process between the same two end states?

Comment: @ChetMiller the words "in finite time" were missing in the title, my bad...

Comment: There is some ambiguity in what is called *adiabatic process* - in the context of Carnot cycle one usually implies a reversible process. However, more generally the word is taken to mean absence of heat exchange.

Comment: @RogerVadim I assume no heat exchange. Can there be two adiabatic processes starting in the same equilibrium state and end in the same equilibrium state both in finite time assuming that there is at least one such?

Comment: Yes, for some adiabatic reversible processes.  For example, shear deformation of a viscous incompressible fluid between two infinite adiabatic parallel plates, the final state depends only on the amount of work done.  Also, stirring of a viscous fluid adiabatically.

Comment: Entropy is a state function. In principle, for a differentiable function of more than one parameter there is more than one path connecting two points. But adiabaticity means a constraint on variables... which I do not fully understand yet. Most likely, the answer depends on the number of parameters.

Comment: @ChetMIller can shear viscous fluid between adiabatic plates be controlled so that it settle down in finite time or only settles asymptotically?

Comment: @ChetMiller By settling I mean to arrive and stay within a given arbitrarily small neighborhood of an equilibrium state with the same order of error when compared to another control path. Admittedly, in the back of my mind I see these finite length irreversible paths, if there is any, as being unique and they must all end up during the same settling time at different states, like nonfocusing optical rays in variable medium, never crossing over the same settling time? In other  words given the equilibration error there may be a constitutive   minimum $\delta t>0$ timing error to settle there.